# Consume Messages from kafka dead letter queue

Tags: apache-kafka, deserialization, kafka-consumer-api, confluent-schema-registry

I've created a sink connector to start consuming from dead letter queue. But it shows schema not found exception as follows:

```
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error retrieving Avro key schema version for id 103925
Caused by: io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.exceptions.RestClientException: Schema not found; error code: 40403
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.sendHttpRequest(RestService.java:295)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.httpRequest(RestService.java:355)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.lookUpSubjectVersion(RestService.java:440)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.lookUpSubjectVersion(RestService.java:427)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.CachedSchemaRegistryClient.getVersionFromRegistry(CachedSchemaRegistryClient.java:236)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.CachedSchemaRegistryClient.getVersion(CachedSchemaRegistryClient.java:364)
    at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer.schemaVersion(AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer.java:116)
    at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer.deserializeWithSchemaAndVersion(AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer.java:158)
```

but messages can be viewed using kafka ui, like kafdrop. how did they deserialize those messages

Answer (score 0):

Notice in the error says **`key`** schema.

Verify the records in your DLQ are actually serialized as Avro, and if not, then don't use `key.converter=...AvroConverter`

Unclear what you're seeing in Kafdrop, but Avro keys are not commonly used for JDBC sinks, for example, and maybe you are only seeing the value of the record. Or, Connect has lost connectivity to your Registry, so it simply fails looking up `id 103925` (Do you really have over 100k unique schemas in your registry? Have you tried to use the Registry REST API directly to see if that ID really exists? And if so, does it describe the data for your DLQ records?)

Comment: The records in the topic are in avro format, and I can see key and value of messages in kafdrop. I tried to search for schema id: 103925 using schema registry API, but unfortunately got 404 not found

Comment: Then sounds at least one record in your topic isn't actually Avro, and that's a bogus record whose bytes got parsed into an int ID. You can look at the consumer group of the sink connector to see which offset its failing at, then try to find those specific records in kafdrop, or from the CLI

Comment: due to this schema not found exception, cannot see my sink connector in the consumer list of the dead letter queue topic

Comment: Okay, so your connector probably shouldn't be reading from the DLQ topic. There's a reason why your original connector actually inserted data into it, such as it not being Avro data. Therefore, you could use ByteArrayConverter instead, for example, and skip the registry completely, but then you'd still need to parse those bytes somehow.... So, to debug, I suggest you use `kafka-console-consumer` directly and see what's actually in that topic